# How do I return data after an AJAX Call to the server has been made?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been playing around this for a bit. My goal is to post my form fields to URL /checkaddress and display the results. The issue is my data object is display empty. **delivery_line_**1 should contain info from JSON content. I've seen examples using Callbacks and jQuery deferred Objects but I can't seem to incorporate them into my code.

My code is below:

```
      submitHandler: function(form) {

        // Submit Handeler 


             $.ajax({

                url: '/checkaddress',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $('form#Form').serialize(),
                success: handleData

              });

             function handleData(data) {
                //do some stuff
                console.log(data.delivery_line_1);

            }


      }
```

My form is:

```
<form id="Form">

    <input class="fname" id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />

    <input class="lname" id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last name" />


</form>
```

My form data that is being posted is firstname=Kalska&lastname=Lamsm

When I go into the Network Tab in Chrome's browser tools, click on the Headers tab I get a Status Code:200 When I click on the response Tab I don't any response. Is this an issue that the server is not responding with any data or is my code incorrect?

Comment: Go into your browser dev tools network and copy the json that actually gets sent. If that property is empty or undefined either the structure you expect is not right or it is not being populated server side.

Comment: Where have you logged `data` itself?

Comment: I would suggest using F12 tools to view the network traffic coming back from your call. You can see exactly what is in your response. It's possible you are getting some sort of error that is being handled silently.

Comment: inside `handleData` log `data`....and so its a `form` with `id` `Form`?

Comment: @MattSpinks I'm getting a successful response message 200

Comment: What's in the response body?

Comment: @MattSpinks I am getting nothing in the response body

Comment: Well then there's your problem (at least the start of it). Nothing is being returned. DO you have the ability to debug your backend code?

Comment: @MattSpinks Not at the moment but I did send a message to our backend guy. Silly question. His code is suppose to return data when it receives form information (which my application is doing) This would not be a code mistake on the front end side since I was able to confirm that data was being sent using Chrome's developer tools would it?

Comment: No, that sounds like it's on the backend.